# Hibernate join table lazy loading

Tags: hibernate, one-to-many, hibernate-mapping, join

I use hibernate 4.1.6.Final. And in my case lazy loading of @OneToOne association with @JoinTable didn't work.

TABLES:

```
CREATE TABLE PERSON
(
"ID"     NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,

"NAME"     VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT "PERSON_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")

);


CREATE TABLE ADDRESS
(
"ID"     NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
"ADDR"     VARCHAR2(200 BYTE) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT "ADDRESS_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID")
);



CREATE TABLE PERSON_ADDRESS
(
"P_ID"        NUMBER NOT NULL,
"A_ID"        NUMBER NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT "PA_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("P_ID","A_ID"),
CONSTRAINT "PERS_FK" FOREIGN KEY ("P_ID") REFERENCES PERSON ("ID"),
CONSTRAINT "ADD_FK"   FOREIGN KEY ("A_ID") REFERENCES ADDRESS ("ID"),
CONSTRAINT "A_UNIQUE"  UNIQUE ("A_ID"),
CONSTRAINT "P_UNIQUE"  UNIQUE ("P_ID")
);
```

and mapping

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMP_SEQ1", sequenceName = "EMP_SEQ")
public class Person {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMP_SEQ1")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long id;

@Column(name = "NAME")
public String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
@JoinTable(name = "PERSON_ADDRESS", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "P_ID"),      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "A_ID"))
public Address address;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ADDRESS")
@SequenceGenerator(name = "EMP_SEQ1", sequenceName = "EMP_SEQ")
public class Address {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "EMP_SEQ1")
@Column(name = "ID")
public Long id;

@Column(name = "ADDR")
public String name;   
}
```

when I get the Person object by id, like

```
 Person person = (Person)session.get(Person.class,1L);
```

hibernate produce this query

```
select
    person0_.ID as ID10_0_,
    person0_.NAME as NAME10_0_,
    person0_1_.A_ID as A1_11_0_ 
from
    PERSON person0_ 
left outer join
    PERSON_ADDRESS person0_1_ 
        on person0_.ID=person0_1_.P_ID 
where
    person0_.ID=?
```

how can I avoid the "left outer join" and lazy load the Address class

Comment: The address is not eagerly-loaded. Only its ID is, in order for Hibernate to be able to create an uninitialized proxy containing the ID of the address, necessary to actually load the address when needed.

Comment: Thanks for replay @JBNizet. But how avoid the "left join with address" when select a person object. For example when using one-to-one mapping with "shared primary key" strategy entity initialization can be avoided by using optional=false attribute.

Comment: Why are you use one-to-one with joinTable ? Add fk-column to person what links on address, and not use joinTable, when lazy initialization will load fk only without any joins.